# knockout.js and Firefox Save Passwords on login form

Tags: firefox, knockout.js

Firefox populates a form with my username/password.  This is using knockout.js to bind the input but it won't update the values on this kind of populating.  Am I missing something say on a page load?  When it populates and the user hits submits, the values are blank.

```
(function (app, $, undefined) {

    app.viewModel = app.viewModel || {};
    app.login = {};

    app.viewModel.login = {
        userName: ko.observable(''),
        password: ko.observable(''),
        returnUrl: ''
    };

    app.viewModel.login.submit = function () {
        sso.login(app.viewModel.login.userName(), app.viewModel.login.password(), app.viewModel.login.returnUrl);
    };

    app.login.init = function (returnUrl) {

        app.viewModel.login.returnUrl = returnUrl;

        ko.applyBindings(app.viewModel);
    };

})(window.app = window.app || {}, jQuery);
```

Comment: Knouckout.js needs to handle the `input` event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way that I have dealt with this in the past is to use a wrapper to the `value` binding that initializes the value from the element's current value.

It would look like (this one is simplified to only work with observables):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.valueWithInit = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        var value = element.value;

        observable(value);   

        ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context);
    },
    update: ko.bindingHandlers.value.update
};
```

So, you would use `valueWithInit` instead of `value`.  You just need to make sure that ko.applyBindings is not called before the autocomplete has been able to do its job.

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/TeFAX/

Comment: Interesting, but it worked, thanks! setTimeout(function () { ko.applyBindings(app.viewModel); }, 1000);

Comment: I wanted to build on this.  If you have two saved credentials for the same form, then this doesn't work.  When you pick a username, it populates the password, but the password doesn't get reflected in the viewmodel.  You have to manually remove it and type it in.

Comment: I got it to work with this below by just rebinding it.   app.viewModel.login.userName.subscribe(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(app.viewModel);
    });

Comment: When you manually type it in, the password gets populated in the textbox but the observable doesnt update.  I thought the applyBindings would work, but it actualy binds the page twice.  Cant  I update the textbox of just the password?

Comment: I tried the fiddle and it doesn't work if you save passwords for multiple users and try to switch between them. Tested in chrome 25.0.1354.0 (dev channel)

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution here not really satisfying. Although the approach is rather interesting, it fails when the user is choosing the account later and the browser does allow to use the stored credentials (e.g. if there are more than one credentials stored). It failed as well when you started typing in the password and deleted to get back to the original password (in Firefox at least).
Additionally, I did not really like the timeout to give the browser time - just not that nice.

**My solution:**
*which isn't really one, but I thought I share nonetheless*

Simple update our model manually before doing the login in the submit callback.
Using jQuery, something like `self.password($("#password").val())` should do it.

Alternatively, using the existing bindings, triggering a change event seems to work as well - e.g. `$("#password").change()`.

The Pros:

- is only for credential fields, so probably a one time thing for your site
- is simple and clean - one or two lines at the proper place
- seems to always work reliably, no matter what browser, credential setup or usage pattern

The Cons:

- breaks again the nice separation Knockout.js provides
- is not a solution but rather a workaround

I will stick with that for now because I found it just reliable working. It would be nice to tell Knockout to reevaluate the bindings directly rather than storing the value back manually or triggering it via the change event. But I haven't found anything so far.

Just thinking a bit ahead - the same problem should arise when the browser auto-completes any form (e.g. like an address) - which means means some sort of general function doing the above would be nice (probably calling the change trigger on each input field of the form)

**Edit:**
Some quick code demonstrating the idea

The HTML:

```
<form id="myForm" data-bind="submit: login">
    Email: <input type="text" data-bind="value: email" /><br/>
    Password: <input type="password" data-bind="value: password" /><br/>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

And the Javascript:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.email = ko.observable("");
    self.password = ko.observable("");

    self.login = function() {
        $("#myForm").find("input").change();

        //Now the observables contain the recent data
        alert(ko.mapping.toJSON(self));
    };
}
```